# Shorten nested ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

If the following data table is given, and we would like to compare x1 consequently with x2 to x5, the following can be used:

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
TDT <- data.table(x1 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                  x2 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                  x3 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                  x4 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2),
                  x5 = round(rnorm(100,0.75,0.3),2))

TDT[,compare := ifelse(x1 < x2,1,ifelse(x1 < x3,2,ifelse(x1 < x4,3,ifelse(x1 < x5,4,5))))]
```

So if `x1 < x2`, then `compare == 1`, etc.

Now in my example, I have a lot more columns to compare x1 with. Is there any way to write this more concisely, i.e. without nested ifelse?

Comment: In your example, it is giving all FALSE, please provide an example which gives all the possibilites

Comment: @akrun I edited the example.

Comment: Thanks, because of the earlier data, I couldn't test it properly.  updated the post

Comment: `max.col(TDT$x1 < cbind(TDT[, -1, with=F], Inf), "first")`

Comment: @user20650  That is a clever option.  I liked it

Comment: cheers Akrun: but needs to be rewritten data.table*ish*

Comment: @user20650  I think it can be changed to `TDT[, compare := max.col(x1 < data.table(.SD, Inf), "first"), .SDcols = x2:x5]`  I was trying with `c(.SD, Inf)` but somehow it returns in error

Comment: good stuff @Akrun, that looks a bit more like it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this using `Map` and `max.col` in `data.table`

```
TDT[, compare := {d1 <- as.data.table(Map(function(x) x1 < x, .SD))
       max.col(d1, "first") *(c(5, 1)[((Reduce(`+`, d1)!=0)+1)])}, .SDcols = x2:x5]

#OP's code
v1 <- TDT[, ifelse(x1 < x2,1,ifelse(x1 < x3,2,ifelse(x1 < x4,3,ifelse(x1 < x5,4,5))))]
identical(v1, TDT$compare)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @user3032689  I changed the answer

Comment: I guess a cleaner alternative to `Map()`/`max.col()`/`Reduce` is to use a simple and flexible loop -- e.g. something like `compare = rep_len(length(TDT), nrow(TDT)); for(i in length(TDT):2) compare[TDT[[i]] > TDT[[1]]] = i - 1L` looks valid

Answer (score 6):

This saves a bit of typing and is easy to read.

```
TDT[, compare := dplyr::case_when(
      x1 < x2 ~ 1,
      x1 < x3 ~ 2,
      x1 < x4 ~ 3,
      x1 < x5 ~ 4,
      TRUE ~ 5)]
```

If you have so many columns that you don't want to mention them all by name, then you could use:

```
apply(TDT, 1, function (x) which(x[1] < x[2:5])[1])
```

where x[2:5] should be replaced by the relevant set of columns.

Comment: I've never used that `:=` operator before. Can you give a short explanation of what it does here? Based on the docs online it wasn't quite clear to me...

Comment: Nor have I. Some kinda crazy `data.table` thing. I think it creates a new column.

Comment: cool thanks though! I read up on it a [little more](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html): _The := operator updates data.table columns in-place (by reference)_  to avoid any kind of shallow or deep copy when replacing or re-assigning parts of data sets. You can use it like so: `DT[, c("colA", "colB", ...) := list(valA, valB, ...)]`

Comment: @patrick see the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) pages