# Replace nested ifelse in data.table

Tags: r, nested, data.table

I want to create a column in my `data.table` which takes the first non `NA` value from a set of given columns:

```r
library(data.table)
o <- data.table(a1 = c(1, NA, NA, NA), 
                a2 = c(NA, 2, NA, NA), 
                a3 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA),
                default = 11:14)
res <- copy(o)
res[, nc := ifelse(!is.na(a1), 
                   a1, 
                   ifelse(!is.na(a2), 
                          a2, 
                          ifelse(!is.na(a3),
                                 a3, 
                                 default)))][]
#    a1 a2 a3 default nc
# 1:  1 NA NA      11  1
# 2: NA  2 NA      12  2
# 3: NA NA  3      13  3
# 4: NA NA NA      14 14
```

Since this becomes quite tedious with a lot of columns, I wanted to replace that by some sort of loop.
I have read [Shorten nested ifelse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045098/shorten-nested-ifelse) and could at least get the position of the first non `NA` column via `max.col`:

```r
(col_ind <- o[, max.col(!sapply(.SD, is.na), "first"), .SDcol = patterns("^a|^default")])
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

How could I now "map" the column position to the column? With matrix subsetting I could do something like  `o[cbind(1:NROW(o), col_ind)]` but this does not work for obvious reasons? Anybody an idea how to solve that issue (no need to stick to the `max.col`  approach if there is a idomatic `data.table`solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some raw ideas:

1) Using `fcase()`, (which is currently available in the development version):

```
o[, nc := fcase(
      !is.na(a1), a1,
      !is.na(a2), a2,
      !is.na(a3), a3,
      rep(TRUE, nrow(o)), as.double(default)
)]
```

2) Using `apply()`:

```
o[, 
  nc := apply(.SD, 1L, function(x) x[!is.na(x)][1L]), 
  .SDcol = patterns("^a|^default")]
```

3) Using `melt()`:

```
o[, row := .I]
o[, nc := o[, melt(.SD, id.vars = "row"), .SDcol = patterns("^a|^default|^row")
            ][!is.na(value), value[1L], by = row]$V1]
o[, row := NULL]
```

4) Using `set()` with your `col_ind` vector:

```
for (i in seq_len(nrow(o))) set(o, i, "nc", value = o[[col_ind[i]]][i])
```

5) Using `max.col()` with matrix numeric indexing:

```
o[, nc := {
    m <- as.matrix(.SD)
    m[cbind(seq.int(.N), max.col(!is.na(m), "first"))]
}]
```

6) Using `fcoalesce()`:

```
o[, names(o) := lapply(.SD, as.integer)][, 
    nc := fcoalesce(.SD)]
```

- Credit for 5 and 6 to chinsoon12.

Comment: Thanks, this compares to `dplyr::case_when`, it helps to avoid some of the ugliness of nested `ifelses` but still requires a lot of hard coding.  For your second solution with `apply`: does that scale well with big `data.tables`?

Comment: @thothal I don't think it will scale very well.

Comment: Nice, I was thinking of `melt` as well! Needed to adapt your code a bit (and also to avoid the creation of `row` in the first place and now it works like a charm.

Comment: @thothal after your edit the results are not the same... (and not equal to your expected output)

Comment: True, I overlooked that - did a rollback. However, your solution still gives me a NULL column. but the correct result is in `row`, so I guess the on the fly by ref semantics don't work as expected.

Comment: @thothal I updated again to avoid the NULL column. There is probably still some room for improvement.

Comment: `fcoalesce` for the win. By far the best balance between readability speed and scalability.

Comment: @thothal brilliant, how could I've forgot about it.